# Optimize Composer Autoloader in Symfony and check if enabled

Tags: php, symfony, autoloader

I have an Symfony 3.4 project and want to optimise the speed by generating all autoloader classes in an file. I used the standard composer dump-autoload for that.

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize --no-dev --classmap-authoritative
```

The generating command gives no errors. Only I don't see speed improvements. How can I check if this is enables? Do I need to include the generated autoload_classmap.php into my app.php file? Can I disable it again?

Comment: How are you testing, and what do you expect to "see"? On an otherwise idle system you're not likely to be able to perceive any difference because it's so small and only really becomes impactful when the system is under IO pressure.

Comment: I'm just viewing some pages and look at the response time in the Symfony debug bar

Comment: If you're seeing the debug bar, it's in dev mode which isn't going to be that fast regardless.

Comment: Ok, but now I used the command on the debug server. Does this mean I need to run the command again after every class change? Or can I change it back?